# Enable-Migrations Command giving Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I was working on ASP.Net boilerplate framework and now that machine is not available where i was working, But i have backup on my Google drive. How i can use that backup properly? Database creation , project running etc??? I am getting error on Enable-Migrations and Update Database Commands

```
 Exception calling "LoadFrom" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///F:\Qubit 
 Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At F:\Qubit Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780 char:5
+     $utilityAssembly = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-P ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
 At F:\Qubit Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781 char:5
+     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

 Exception calling "CreateInstanceFrom" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///F:\Qubit 
 Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll' or one of its       dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception 
from HRESULT: 0x80131515)"
At F:\Qubit Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:809 char:5
+     $domain.CreateInstanceFrom(
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileLoadException
```

Comment: check that there's this file: F:\Qubit Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.PowerShell.Utility.dll

Comment: Yes this file exist at given path. Now what to do with this? Sir @Alper

Answer (score 1):

Using the Package Manager, re-install Entity Framework:

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
```

Then install it for each project:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: check this topic for further information -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318107/enabling-code-first-entity-framework-vs-web-express-2012/14994432#14994432

Comment: Sir @Alper this error occurred on installing entity-framework again File F:\Qubit Systems\ShipperBuyerV1\module-zero-template-2.1.1\src\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.

Comment: Sir @Alper "install.p‌​s1"

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

- Run VS as Administrator
- Clean & Rebuild
- Remove the obj folder

In some case you can use Update-Package -Reinstall to complete reinstall all package