# Why can't I successfully create a TCPListener

Tags: vb.net, tcpclient

I'm following the MSDN tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478452.aspx) which details how to make a basic client-server TCP chat program.

I have all the code in place, and it is compiling, however I'm hitting an issue in the socketClient class, when trying to create the new TcpListener object.

The tutorial says to use the line:

```
mobjClient = New TcpClient("localhost", 5000)
```

However, on running this, I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: **A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup**

Playing with the hostname part of the constructor, I get an identical message for the following as parameters. The function call returns the name of the machine correctly.

```
(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(), 5000)
```

I also tried using the IP of the machine, both as 127.0.0.1 and it's actual IP. Using an IP gives a slightly different error of

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
>   Additional information: **An invalid argument was supplied**

I also found [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/df18bd89-4468-45a7-ab9d-2a2b04376d97/multi-clients-vb2008-express?forum=wcf) which is someone else using the same tutorial, which supplies complete code.

Answer (score 3):

Found a partial solution [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375615/vb-net-socket-exception-only-while-debugging)

Apparently VS.net is very picky about the fact that the assembly is running on a network location. While the above links problem isn't the same, it's definitely related, as moving the project to the local drive caused the TCPListener to work properly.

I now have other bugs to work out, but I believe they are unrelated. I also could not get his app.config solution to solve my problem. Only by copying to the local disk would the program run.

Answer (score 0):

mobjClient As New TcpClient("localhost", 5000)

Comment: You might want to elaborate on that a bit.  There is no context to your answer.