# 'Could not load file or assembly' compilation errors

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dll

Like many others I am getting the "Could not load file or assembly ... .dll".  This problem happens when I try to compile as there is then a single error.   I have tried adding a reference to System.Data.Entity and rebuilding, as well as also trying various things out from this stackoverflow answered question:

[Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0 in MVC4 Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431975/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-net-http-version-2-0-0-0-in-mvc4-web-ap)

I have tried the "Copy Local = True" under properties under References for the particular .dll (It was already set to True), as well as "Always Copy" the .dll in question which is in the bin folder.

I have also tried to find the "runtime" code in the Web.Config file, there however is none in either that or the sub-files (web.debug.config and web.release.config).  I thought that perhaps I could modify the version.  There are about 10 other .dll references which seem to be working.  I also did get the compilation and part of the first page to run the first time, but not after that.  Error information is at the bottom.

I have read that there seems to be a problem with NuGet but I don't know if I should remove it as I don't know what it does and might find it useful later.  I am using Visual Web Developer Express 2012.

```
'Could not load file or assembly 'ComponentArt.Web.UI, Version=2008.1.1202.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)'   C:\Users\Brian\Desktop
```

Comment: Is this similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524423/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-hresult-0x80131515-when-adding-controller-to-m

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be using the ComponentArt dll that depends on WebForms in MVC4 project. You need to create a WebForms project and then you will be able to add that DLL.