# VS2010 Cannot edit devenv.exe.config as crss.exe has a lock on it

Tags: visual-studio-2010, csrss

I am attempting to edit devenv.exe.config to implement the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524423/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-hresult-0x80131515-when-adding-controller-to-m).

as i believe it will solve an issue i am having with building a project.

I cannot however edit the file as csrss.exe has a lock on it. A restart did not help. This exe is an os level exe which i cannot kill without taking down the os. i don't know what it has a lock on the config file as no vs tools are running.

I have tried to boot into safe mode but have not been able to.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 9):

Try running your text editor as an administrator.  I ran into the same problem where it appeared that csrss.exe was locking the file.  However, it turned out to be a permissions problem stemming from the fact that the file resided under "C:\Program Files (X86)".  Once I ran Notepad++ as administator I was able to edit the file.