# Is OpenXML SDK required to be installed in every computer that will run my program?

Tags: vb.net, dll, closedxml

Is there a way to deploy my application (which uses ClosedXML) and not be required to install OpenXMLSDKv2.msi on each computer?

If I uninstall the sdk I get this error at runtime:

[image]

I already referenced DocumentFormat.OpenXml (copy local = true) and WindowsBase (also copy local true, despite being not necessary.

DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll and ClosedXML.dll are both on the bin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll and ClosedXML.dll are both on the bin folder.

This should be enough, no installation required.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524423/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-hresult-0x80131515-when-adding-controller-to-m) for other takes on this error (for all dlls, not just ClosedXML / OpenXml).

Comment: I just needed to click "Unblock" in the file properties dialog, thank you very much!