# Adding Open XML References to a Visual Studio Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vsto, openxml, office-interop

I am adding Open XML functionality to an Office VSTO add-in built in Visual Studio 2012 and 2010.  This requires adding two references to my VS project:  DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll and WindowsBase.dll.  My concern is that these DLLs won't be present on end users' computers, and the code will throw an error when run on their computers.  Two questions:

1)  Is it safe to assume that these two DLLs are present on my users' PCs (just like I can safely assume that System.Xml.dll is)?  Do they install automatically with Windows and/or Office, or are they included in some sort of Windows/Office update that everyone generally has installed?

2)  If not, what is the best way to ensure that my add-in will run on their computers?  Do I need to include these as prerequisites in my installer?  Set the CopyLocal property = True?

I did find this similar question on SO:

[Is OpenXML SDK required to be installed in every computer that will run my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762054/is-openxml-sdk-required-to-be-installed-in-every-computer-that-will-run-my-progr)

but the entering assumption is that CopyLocal is already set to True.  I would prefer avoid that if possible.  Also, the solution is not really a solution because the author says no action is required.  Vallo's comment to the accepted solution seems more helpful, but it appears to require unintuitive additional action by the end user that I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` is part of the **Office Open XML SDK**. There's no reason for your clients to install the whole **SDK**.

So yes, you have to ship `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll` to them by setting `CopyLocal` to `True`.

`WindowsBase.dll` is part of the *.NET Framework* so you don't have to manually include this one.

Comment: What is the "correct version" of .NET Framework?  Are you simply saying to mark the necessary prerequisites in the setup project, generally?  If so, please consider editing your response to remove the last paragraph it is a bit ambiguous and beyond the scope here.

Comment: It's simply the one your project uses.

Comment: Ok, so other readers can ignore the last paragraph in the answer; that goes without saying.

Comment: You're right I guess, it might be confusing. I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

So let me answer you with my knowledge

1. Assuming user would have Open XML installed is not a good move. And as you think it doesn't come with any updates or office installation [Open XML works independent from office packages. That's why you can generate Open XML files without Excel or any other office package]
2. Yes , the best thing is to deliver .dll with your solution to end user. Here is the catch, when you install Open XML SDK on your machine you went through a license agreement. I welcome you to remove and re-install Open XMl SDK so you can see license agreement contents [you won't find that agreement in any other place]. It clearly say .dll is free to use and deliver [yes with some restrictions- just go through it].

So what you can do ?

I'm currently working with a product where I had to use Open XML SDK. What I did was I added .dll to our product's third party resources section and delivered it to customers. I think that's the easiest thing you can do.

Else you have another option. You can ask customers who use your product and who needs to use Open XML dependence functionality in your product to install Open XML SDK to their machines.

In conclusion you need .dll to have in your machine locally to use Open XML SDK. So your customers too should have .dll with them to get Open XML SDK dependency functionality.

Hope you got some idea and I helped with your situation.

NOTE - You  "DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll" is the .dll I'm taliking here. "WindowsBase.dll" is present in .net framework

Comment: So, assuming that my users to have Office installed (which is a safe assumption in my case), would they already have Open XML SDK installed?  In other words, does it install with Office?

Comment: No.. Open XML SDK will not come with Office packages