# every time I try to create the controller I get the following error message: There was an error running the selected code generator...'

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web, I am attempting to create a new controller in my asp.net MVC application. I am using Entity Framework 5 with code first (.NET 4.5).

I want Visual Studio to create the template for me - However, every time I try to create the controller I get the following error message:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'unable to
>   retrieve metadata for 'CII.Domain.Password'. unable to load the
>   specified metadata resource

Comment: Can you give some screenshot of your project and the error please?

Comment: I made changes in the DB and then I updated the model ('UPDATE MODEL FROM DATABASE'), and since you can not access at all to DB and add a controller. Is there another place where there is change after the update? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this problem many times.
And after "Bulid" Is resolved!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error myself - I tried to search for solutions on StackOverflow and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524423/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-hresult-0x80131515-when-adding-controller-to-m), suggesting Admin Rights or to add `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true" />` to `C:[Visual Studio 2010 Install Dir]\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`.
()

The solution I had was to build with any of the latest changes, clean the solution and then rebuild.

I know it's a simple answer but doing this worked for me - I had not built the solution since adding a new Model and when I tried to add the controller scaffolding it was giving me an error. So: Build, Clean, Rebuild the solution after the model is added.